# Unable to start tomcat with 80 port in Google Compute Engine

Tags: java, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, centos7

I used Google Compute Engine instance with CentOS7 and Tomcat 8.Tomcat server works fine with port 8080 but socket exception occurred when i change port to 80.
Tomcat exception is,

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:219)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:265)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
```

My firewall roles,
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSQU0.png)

I already followed 
[Google cloud Compute Engine refuse outer access through apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643758/google-cloud-compute-engine-refuse-outer-access-through-apache2)
But no works.. Please advice .......

Comment: A) dont link to **pictures** of content that is text. All of the relevant information should come as [mcve], and nicely formatted/indented text with your question B) I then think that your question might be better suited for segfault.com You are asking how to configure your server setup. This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: This is something that a lot of cloud hosts do. Check your environment variables for something like `PORT`.

Comment: Where can i check something like PORT in cloud engine?

Comment: `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`, users can't open ports below 1024, only root can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google cloud platform: cannot start java https server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356163/google-cloud-platform-cannot-start-java-https-server)

Comment: you should try with sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46357383/5813861) by @gdahlm,

Ports below 1024 on linux/Unix are "privileged ports", which require elevated privileges to create.

As you are in GCP (Google Cloud Platform), you have several options.

Use a high port above 1024 as a non-privlaged user and:

- Connect to that high port in your url https://foo:8443
- Use the GCP
  network or HTTP/HTTPS load balancer to forward port 443 to a high
  port
- Leverage IP tables to forward packets from 443 to a high port
  inside the VM instance
- Run the service using suid, sudo or other
  method
- Grant the _CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE_ capabilities(7) to the
  process.

Those last two options have complex security implications
   and should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

A community member previously had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177453/tomcat-8-running-but-refused-to-connect). He was able to [fix](https://wolfpaulus.com/java/tomcat-ssl/) his issue by running this command:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service+ep /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres the command i used for iptables to forward port 80 to 8080:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

don't forget to do the same for 443